# gpg2 pinentry fails without X

Tags: gpg, gpg-agent, pinentry

**What is working**

My gpg-agent pinentry works fine under X.  I can run

```
echo "test" | gpg2 -ase --default-recipient-self | gpg2
```

to cache my passwords and later run `killall gpg-agent -1` to flush them.

By default, it opens pinentry-gtk (from the looks of it) and prompts me for my password.

**What is not working**

However, if I try to run the same command without an X server, the it appears that gpg2 is hanging (no prompt or anything).  If I kill it, then I can see that there is also a `pinentry` process which continues to exist but not anywhere useful.

**What I expect to happen**

I expect that running `gpg2` without an X server would give me a pinentry-curses prompt, the same way that `pass` does.  Additionally, I seem to remember that with older version of gpg, it just prompted me for my password from stdin, and I'm not quite sure why that doesn't happen either.

**What I have tried**

I have tried the following "fixes" but none have caused the aforementioned command to execute properly.  In fact, forcing pinentry-curses causes the aforementioned command to fail even with the X environment (`pass` still works).

- Setting `pinentry-program /usr/bin/pinentry-curses` in `gpg-agent.conf``
- Starting gpg-agent like this: `gpg-agent --daemon --keep-tty --use-standard-socket --pinentry-program=/usr/bin/pinentry-curses`
- using an environment variable: `export PINENTRY_USER_DATA="USE_CURSES=1”`

*Background info*

I have a nearly empty .gpg-agent config file; all it has is cache timeouts.

I am calling gpg-agent directly upon login like `eval $(gpg-agent --daemon)`.  I am not booting into X so I use getty to log in.

Answer (score 3):

Oops... the answer was in the first screen's worth of `man gpg-agent`.  I needed to add the following lines to my ~/.bashrc:

```
GPG_TTY=$(tty)
export GPG_TTY
```

The incorrect value of GPG_TTY explains why pinentry-curses was running, but not where I needed it to.

*note:* Since the output of `tty` changes between the console login and after I start my X server, this needs to be run on every ~/.bashrc (whereas most of my export'd environment variables are configured to only run on login).

Answer (score 0):

If you are switching between X and tty often you may want to run

```
gpg-connect-agent updatestartuptty /bye > /dev/null
```

To set it to the current environment